# General solution of 1st ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I am trying to figure out the general solution of this initial value problem:

\begin{align}
   \dot{X}(t) &= aX(t) + bY(t) + f(t) \\
   \dot{Y}(t) &= cX(t) + dY(t) + g(t) \\
   X(0) &= X_0 \\
Y(0) &= Y_0
\end{align}

where $f(t)$, $g(t)$ can be any functions.
Could this system have the exact general solution?

So far, I just thought of converting into second order differential equation and still stuck while trying to get the general solution. Not sure if this is the correct way to get the solution.
Please help me with this.

Comment: Such a general formula in terms of an integral can be found in https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Book%3A_Differential_Equations_for_Engineers_(Lebl)/3%3A_Systems_of_ODEs/3.9%3A_Nonhomogeneous_systems (e.g. equation (3.9.2)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear differential equation with non homogeneous term. The solution can be found with the "method of variations of constants".

First let us set
\begin{align*}
z(t) & =\left(\begin{array}{c}
X(t)\\
Y(t)
\end{array}\right)\\
A & =\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{array}\right)\\
y(t) & =\left(\begin{array}{c}
f(t)\\
g(t)
\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}
Then your ODE can be written as
\begin{align*}
\dot{z}(t) & =Az(t)+y(t)\\
z(0) & =z_{0}.
\end{align*}

It can be seen (just differentiate to check) that the solution of
the above is
$$
z(t)=e^{tA}z(0)+\int_{0}^{t}ds \, e^{(t-s)A}y(s).
$$

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome